# main program work good , but when put it into a function doesn't work pyQt

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt4

I have a `mainWindow` and a `Frame` in `PyQt`, in My `main`  program i have the following code:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
Frame = QtGui.QFrame()
ui = Ui_Frame()
ui.setupUi(Frame)
Frame.show()    
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Above code, Shows a Main Window and a Frame,

I created a class to functionality my program:

```
class ShowHide(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def showFrameMaterials(self):
        Frame = QtGui.QFrame()
        ui = Ui_Frame()
        ui.setupUi(Frame)
        Frame.show()
        print "it's debugging"

    def showMainWindow(self):
        MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()
```

It causes i have two functions that i call `showMainWindow()` and `showFrameMaterials()` then i changed my main such as :

```
obj = ShowHide()
obj.showMainWindow()
obj.showFrameMaterials()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But i  didn't see any windows , i back to code and put code of `mainwindow`  into main program and call `showFrameMaterials()` such as:

```
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    obj = ShowHide()
    obj.showMainWindow()
    obj.showFrameMaterials()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But i just see MainWindow ...

**Question:** *Where's My problem?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't seeing any windows in the class based version because the function calls finalise and your PyQt objects are being garbage collected.  In the simple first case you have, the variables containing your PyQt objects remain in scope for the duration.

In this simple case, the easiest way to see this in action is store your PyQt objects in instance variables, ie. `self.Frame` and `self.MainWindow` to retain references to the object so that Python doesn't garbage collect them.

Generally you would not work with PyQt in this fashion.  You subclass the relevant object and do setup in the initialiser.